# Marketing Cloud Storage Limit - Best practices

Tags: marketing-cloud, history-tracking, storage-limit

Is there a way to calculate if the storage limit within my Marketing Cloud account (45gb) will be enough for me?

I want to be able to store contacts, subscribers, trcking data, Images and emails in content builder. How can I know in advanced if 45gb will be enough for me? I want to know in advance so I can decide wether I host my images outside Marketing Cloud or if I will be able to access old tracking data.

what would be the best practice / suggestion in this case?

Thank you!